# Angular 2 Error during evaluation of "click" following the tutorial

Tags: angular

I was following [this part of the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) for AngularJS 2, but when I try to select a "hero" element from the list I receive errors like:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.onSelect is not a function
```

This is the part of the template with the click binding:

```
<ul class="heroes">
   <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
      (click)="onSelect(hero)">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the class AppComponent where I define the onSelect function:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

I even tried to copy the code exactly how it is in the tutorial but still receive the errors. What's wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure that template must be part of `AppComponent`

Comment: Are you sure that the typescript file has been recompiled correctly, and that you have refreshed the page to reload the generated JS file? Look in your dev tools "Source" tab if the app.js file has a onSelect function.

Comment: A similar error might occur if you define the return type of the method, as in `onSelect(hero: Hero): void { /*...*/ }`. Just remove the return type to make it work in that case.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and solved it by making a dummy change in heroes.component.ts. 
I added a space and saved. Then removed the space and saved. It forced a proper refresh of angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your Code works fine for me here is working plunkr using your code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vbinFbGtB7oRoW8cJHwb?p=preview

i assumed heros as object like this,

```
heroes = [{'id':1,'name':'pardeep'}, {'id':2,'name':'jain'}];
```

Yes as said by @eric in comment make sure your HTML file load by AppComponent, secondly make sure your typescript file compiled properly.

Comment: Ok I was working on cloud9... I tried to restart the server and now it works fine. Maybe the file I was working on was not saved properly before. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your method `onSelect()` must be in `heroes.component.ts` and it works fine.

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes = HEROES;

  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(hero: Hero){ this.selectedHero = hero; }

}
```